# matplotlib figure to numpy array without white borders

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm trying to find a way to convert a matplotlib figure to a numpy array without any white spaces or borders.

I found out that if I use the code below, I'll get something pretty close, but the numpy array "data" would still have some white borders. The white border (white changes as I scale the window) is saved as part of the numpy array but I only want the content.

Is there any way to get rid of this white area?

[image: white borders]

```
fig = plt.figure(frameon=False)
ax = plt.Axes(fig, [0., 0., 1., 1.])
ax.set_axis_off()
ax.set_ylim(height, 0)
ax.set_xlim(0, width)
ax.axis('off')
fig.add_axes(ax)

ax.imshow(myimage) # Plus lots of other things

plt.show() # fig.canvas.draw() also works the same
data = np.fromstring(fig.canvas.tostring_rgb(), dtype=np.uint8, sep='')
data = data.reshape(fig.canvas.get_width_height()[::-1] + (3,))
plt.close()
```

A similar question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8632290/convert-matplotlib-figure-to-numpy-array-without-any-borders-frame-or-axis) previously but the author's own work-around with PIL doesn't fit what I need.

Comment: You could try using the `figsize` argument of `plt.figure()` to specify a figure size that has the same aspect ratio as your image.  But this seems like an indirect method to accomplish what you want, and I don't know if it will perfectly eliminate the margins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess `subplots_adjust` is the key here. Seems to work with a toy example but it would be great it you could provide minimal working code to see if it works in your use case.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
# mpl.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = np.ones((100, 200))
img[25:75, 50:150] = 0

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca()

ax.imshow(img)
ax.axis('tight')

plt.subplots_adjust(0,0,1,1,0,0)

plt.show()

data = np.fromstring(fig.canvas.tostring_rgb(), dtype=np.uint8, sep='')
w, h = fig.canvas.get_width_height()
data = data.reshape((h, w, 3))

plt.close()
```

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks

Comment: plt.subplots_adjust(0,0,1,1,0,0)   This is what one needs to do